# React/Redux - mapDispatchToProps. Props undefined

Tags: reactjs, reduce

I'm looking for information in a database, in an app with react. In the actions.js file I can see the response.data data, when I put a console.table.

But even exporting, when I try to display the information, the variable's value comes as undefined.

I've already looked at the original file I'm using to learn, and I couldn't see where the error is.

action.js

```
import { CLEAR_SEARCH, SEARCH_CUSTOMERS } from "./actionTypes";

import Axios from "axios";
import { SEARCH_CUSTOMERS_URL } from "../../configs";

export const searchCustomers = (lat, lng, query) => dispatch => {
    Axios.post(SEARCH_CUSTOMERS_URL, {
        q: query,
    })
    .then(response => {
            const customers = response.data;
            
            console.log( "services/searchCustomers/actions.js, line 30" );
            console.log( customers ); //ok, showing data
        
            return dispatch({ type: SEARCH_CUSTOMERS, payload: customers });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
};

export const clearSearch = () => dispatch => {
    const customers = [];
    return dispatch({ type: CLEAR_SEARCH, payload: customers });
};
```

reducer.js

```
import { CLEAR_SEARCH, SEARCH_CUSTOMERS } from "./actionTypes";

const initialState = {
    customers: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SEARCH_CUSTOMERS:
            return { ...state, customers: action.payload };

        case CLEAR_SEARCH:
            return { ...state, customers: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

actionTypes.js

```
export const SEARCH_CUSTOMERS = "SEARCH_CUSTOMERS";
export const CLEAR_SEARCH = "CLEAR_SEARCH";
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { clearSearch, searchCustomers } from "../../../../services/searchCustomers/actions";

import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DelayLink from "../../../helpers/delayLink";
import Ink from "react-ink";
import LazyLoad from "react-lazyload";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";

import CustomerSearch from "../../CustomerSearch";
import CustomerSearchList from "../CustomerSearchList";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { debounce } from "../../../helpers/debounce";
import ContentLoader from "react-content-loader";

class SelectCustomer extends Component {
    state = {
        open: false,
        queryLengthError: false,
        loading: false,
        showBgImage: true,
        nothingFound: false,
    };

    handleCustomerSearch = debounce((query) => {
        // call to searchCustomers search API
        if (query.length >= 3) {            
            this.props.searchCustomers(
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userSetAddress")).lat,
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userSetAddress")).lng,
                query
            );  
            
            console.table( this.props ); //customers is undefined
            
            this.setState({
                queryLengthError: false,
                loading: true,
                nothingFound: false,
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({ queryLengthError: true });
        }       
    }, 400);

    componentDidMount() {
        //others
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        //others
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {      
        //this.props.customers is undefined
        if (this.props.customers !== nextProps.customers) {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
        }
        
        // console.log(nextProps.customers.length);

        if (nextProps.customers) {
            if (nextProps.customers.length === 0 ) {
                this.setState({ showBgImage: true, nothingFound: true });
            } else {
                this.setState({ showBgImage: false, nothingFound: false });
            }
        }
        
        //Overlay/Dialog.
        if (nextProps.confirmSelectCustomerOpen === false) {
            this.setState({ open: false });
        }
        if (nextProps.confirmSelectCustomerOpen === true) {
            this.setState({ open: true });
        }
    }
    
    //Overlay/Dialog
    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
    };
    
    render() {  
                
        return (
            <React.Fragment>                
                <Dialog
                    fullWidth={true}
                    fullScreen={false}
                    open={this.state.open}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                    style={{ width: "100%", margin: "auto" }}
                    PaperProps={{ style: { backgroundColor: "#fff", borderRadius: "10px" } }}
                >       
                
                {this.state.queryLengthError && (
                    <div className="auth-error" style={{ marginBottom: "4rem" }}>
                        <div className="">{localStorage.getItem("searchAtleastThreeCharsMsg")}</div>
                    </div>
                )}
                
                
                <CustomerSearch searchFunction={this.handleCustomerSearch} />
                
                
                {this.state.loading && (
                    {/*loading*/}
                )}
                
                
                {/* Here Should list customers */}              
                {this.props.customers && this.props.customers.length > 0 && (
                    <CustomerSearchList customers={this.props.customers} />
                )}
                
                
                {this.state.showBgImage && (
                    <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-100">
                        <img
                            className="img-fluid explore-bg"
                            src="/assets/img/various/explore-bg.png"
                            alt={localStorage.getItem("restaurantSearchPlaceholder")}
                        />
                    </div>
                )}
                {this.state.nothingFound && (
                    <div className="auth-error" style={{ marginBottom: "4rem" }}>
                        <div className="error-shake">{localStorage.getItem("exploreNoResults")}</div>
                    </div>
                )}

                </Dialog>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    customers: state.customers  
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { searchCustomers, clearSearch }
)(SelectCustomer);
```

CustomerSearch/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Ink from "react-ink";

class CustomerSearch extends Component {
    state = {
        customer: ""
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        this.searchInput.focus();
    }
    static contextTypes = {
        router: () => null
    };

    handleInputChange = e => {
        this.setState({ customer: e.target.value });
        this.props.searchFunction(e.target.value);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="col-12 p-0">
                    <div className="block m-0">
                        <div className="block-content p-0">
                            <div className="input-group search-box">
                                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        className="btn search-navs-btns"
                                        style={{ position: "relative" }}
                                        onClick={this.context.router.history.goBack}
                                    >
                                        <i className="si si-arrow-left" />
                                        <Ink duration="500" />
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                
                                {/*
                                placeholder do input
                                {localStorage.getItem("restaurantSearchPlaceholder")}
                                */}
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    className="form-control search-input"
                                    placeholder="Pesquisar Cliente"
                                    value={this.state.customer}
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                    ref={input => {
                                        this.searchInput = input;
                                    }}
                                />

                                <div className="input-group-append">
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn search-navs-btns" style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                                        <i className="si si-magnifier" />
                                        <Ink duration="500" />
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default CustomerSearch;
```

CustomerSearchList/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import DelayLink from "../../../helpers/delayLink";
import Ink from "react-ink";
import LazyLoad from "react-lazyload";

class CustomerSearchList extends Component {
    render() {
        const { customers } = this.props;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                
                    {customers.map((customer) => (
                        <div key={customer.id} className="col-xs-12">
                            <DelayLink
                                to={"../stores/" + customer.id}
                                delay={200}
                                className="block block-link-shadow text-center light-bottom-border"
                            >
                                <Ink duration="500" />
                            </DelayLink>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default CustomerSearchList;
```

reducers.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
```

....
....
import customerSearchReducer from "./searchCustomers/reducer";
import addressesReducer from "./addresses/reducer";
....
....

```
export default combineReducers({
    ...
    customers: customerSearchReducer,
    addresses: addressesReducer,
    ...
});
```

SEARCH_CUSTOMERS_URL - URL to php, get data:

```
$response = ['customers' => $customers];

Output customers: Array(3)
0: {id: 2, name: "Customer 1", email: "customer1@gmail.com"}
1: {id: 3, name: "Customer 2", email: "customer2@gmail.com"}
2: {id: 4, name: "Customer 3", email: "customer3@gmail.com"}
```

It's 3 days racking my brain. I did some research but I couldn't solve the problem. I'm new to react/reduce and was trying to figure it out based on this script.

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk or some other middleware?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the `console.log( customers ); //ok, showing data`? Just to see the data you're getting.

Comment: Steve Bunting: In another system file, which is not currently being used, there is this import: import thunk from "redux-thunk";

Comment: AWolf: https://imgur.com/WwDxT1C

Comment: Yes but are you using it? What does your `createStore()` look like?

Comment: File store.js:
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

export default (initialState) => {
 initialState = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("state")) || initialState;
 const middleware = [thunk];

 const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
   applyMiddleware(...middleware)   
  )
 );
......
.....
.....
return store;
};

Comment: What does your rootReducer look like?

Comment: Steve Bunting. Through your questions I went to re-evaluate the script, and I saw an error. I hadn't included the reduce that I created along with the others that came in the system, in export default combineReducers. Thanks for your help. I spent a lot of time looking for the problem elsewhere and I didn't realize it.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments... add searchCustomer reducer to rootReducer.